# Using Splice() function, how do I remove specific array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, splice

When an image is clicked, my code is supposed to adds the images `_id` details to the `clickedImagesArray` array. This it does successfully. However when the image is clicked again, my code fails to remove it from the `clickedImagesArray` array.

Find below my code:

```
"click .image": function (event) {

var clickedImage = [this._id];
var clicked = this._id;
var clickedImagesArray = Session.get('clickedImages');

clickedImage.forEach(function (clicked){
    //#### If no duplcate then push() 
    if (clickedImage.indexOf(clicked) ==-1) {
        alert("NOOOO Duplicates!" + clicked);  
        clickedImagesArray.push({imageId: clicked});
        }
    else if (clickedImage.indexOf(clicked) == 0) {
    //#### Else when duplcate found delete duplicate
        alert("Found Duplicates!" + clicked);       
        clickedImagesArray.splice({imageId: clicked});
```

I have a feeling I am not using the splice() function correctly.

```
        }     
  }); 

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrase: "Search, and research". This would have been trivial to solve yourself by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the index in the array that contains your value.
and then use splice to remove that record from the index.

`splice(startIndex, deleteCount)`

**startIndex:** is the index that you want to start deleting from
**deleteCount:** the number of records that you want to delete, starting from the `startIndex`

```
// find the index of the imageId in the array.
var index = clickedImage.indexOf(clicked);

// if item is found in the array remove it.
if (index !== -1) {
  // remove one item starting from the index.
  clickedImage.splice(index, 1);
}
```

read the documentation in MDN.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Wow... Thanks! your code plus the description are very simple/clear and easy to understand. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a mistake here:

```
else if (clickedImage.indexOf(clicked) == 0) {
```

You should change to:

```
else if (clickedImage.indexOf(clicked) != -1) {
```

This is because you don´t know the exact index of your element.

Oh, and the splice is wrong too, you need to find the index of the element to remove it, like this:

```
clickedImagesArray.splice(clickedImage.indexOf(clicked), 1);
```